# Bibliographystyle invalid

Tags: biblatex, naming

I'm having a problem with using bibliography styles.

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{ref}
```

If in the document I write:

```
\printbibliography
```

I get a version of the bibliography, but with the headline **Bibliography**, and I want it to say References. When I try to include `\bibliographystyle{plain}` (I have tried different ones as well) I only get the message:

```
package biblatex error: \bibliographystyle invalid.
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: If you want to choose a style in biblatex, you have to do so as a package option, e.g. `\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Note also that newer versions of `biblatex` require you to write `\addbibresource{ref.bib}` instead of the older command, `\bibliography{ref}`.

Comment: Doens't work, I think. I'm using biber with `style=plain` and it generates tons of errors with `style 'plain' not found`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66320/bibtex-plain-style-for-biblatex

Answer (score 10):

You could also define the name in the optional argument to `\printbibliography`:

```
\printbibliography[title=References]
```

Answer (score 7):

The heading for the bibliography is decided by the class you're using (and that you should have mentioned).

The `article` class uses the string that's stored in `\refname`, while `report` and `book` use `\bibname`. From your question it seems that

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
```

should do the trick. Note that the `\bibliographystyle` command must not be used when using `biblatex`.

Comment: If I use `biblatex` how then should I change the style? If you say that we cannot use `\bibliographystyle`.

Comment: @zygimantus The title of this question might sound harsh, but don't worry, just look at the resources in the answers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots

Answer (score 5):

Try this in the preamble to change the heading:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References}}
```