# Bibtex plain style for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to emulate the traditional BibTeX styles (plain, abbrv, unsrt, alpha) as closely as possible with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/how-to-emulate-the-traditional-bibtex-styles-plain-abbrv-unsrt-alpha-as-clo)

In `bibtex` I use:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

I switched to `biblatex`. I'm trying:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=plain]{biblatex}
```

It doesn't work. `style=ieee` and `style=apa` works but I want to have `plain` style in `biblatex`. Is that possible?

Comment: `biblatex` doesn't work with traditional `bst` styles. Use `\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}` or (as `numeric` is the default)  simply `\usepackage{biblatex}` for an approximation of the traditional `plain` style. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52106/510

Comment: @lockstep `numeric` only writes the first author and states `et al.` I want to have all authors on the `References`.

Comment: Try the `maxnames=99` option.

Comment: also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58152